# python, rearrange the list to show the item which contains in most list

Tags: python, list

I have several list with their titles such as this:
The way I create this kind of list is using dictionary:

```
myOwnList = {'A' : [1,2,3,4],
             'B' : [1,2,4], 
             'C' : [1,2,3],
             'D' : [1,2,3,4]
             }

Visually, this is it should look like:

A B C D
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3   3 3
4 4   4
```

What I want to do is to rearrange the above list:

```
myOwnListNew = {1 : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                2 : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                3 : ['A', 'C', 'D'],
                4 : ['A', 'B', 'D'],
                }

visually:

1 A B C D
2 A B C D
3 A C D
4 A B D
```

I am not sure what this type of re arrangement is called, it doesn't look like transpose.

Any suggestions how I should implement this in python, should I use simple list, or dictionary? Thanks

Comment: `Rearrange the list` ? How does the list look like? Can you post some python code? What have you tried ?

Comment: thats not what a list looks like ... do you have a text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct translation is, to me, the simplest. It's also of a lower complexity than Ffisegydd's answer:

```
lists = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'B': [1, 2,    4],
    'C': [1, 2, 3   ],
    'D': [1, 2, 3, 4]
}

from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)
for letter, items in lists.items():
    for item in items:
        out[item].append(letter)

dict(out)
#>>> {1: ['A', 'C', 'D', 'B'], 2: ['A', 'C', 'D', 'B'], 3: ['A', 'C', 'D'], 4: ['A', 'D', 'B']}
```

FWIW, this *is* a transposition, but of a masked array:

```
df
#>>>       A      B      C     D
#>>> 0  True   True   True  True
#>>> 1  True   True   True  True
#>>> 2  True  False   True  True
#>>> 3  True   True  False  True

df.T
#>>>       0     1      2      3
#>>> A  True  True   True   True
#>>> B  True  True  False   True
#>>> C  True  True   True  False
#>>> D  True  True   True   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a dictionary constructed such that A, B, C, D are the keys and the numbers are in lists then the code below will convert your dictionary to a new dictionary which is "inverted".

```
d = dict(A=[1,2,3,4], B=[1,2,4], C=[1,2,3], D=[1,2,3,4])

# Create a set of all possible values.
values = set(value for x in d.values() for value in x)

new_d = {key:[k for k, v in d.items() if key in v] for key in values}

print(new_d)
# {1: ['C', 'B', 'D', 'A'], 2: ['C', 'B', 'D', 'A'], 3: ['C', 'D', 'A'], 4: ['B', 'D', 'A']}
```

Because you're working with dictionaries and sets, the ordering of the letters may not be what you'd expect. You can always sort these yourself after the fact if needs be, or add a `sorted()` function around the list comprehension so it would be

```
new_d = {key:sorted([k for k, v in d.items() if key in v]) for key in values}

print(new_d)
# {1: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 2: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 3: ['A', 'C', 'D'], 4: ['A', 'B', 'D']}
```

Comment: FWIW, you can just do `{value for x in d.values() for value in x}`.